# Read file line into lists delimited by a specific string (sharp "#")

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My file content is something like:

```
############################  
Data1  
133  
124  
FRE  
new  
Cable  
Sat  
############################  
DataB  
233  
445  
DEU  
Old  
Sat  
###########################  
MyValue  
4566  
455  
ITA  
NEW  
###########################  
MyValue5  
455  
22332  
Eng  
Sat  
Cable  
##############################
```

What I need is to put each of them into a list and the separator must be the "#":

The result here must be:

```
mylist1=["Data1","133","124","FRE","new","Cable","Sat"]   
mylist2=["DataB","233","445","DEU","Old","Sat"]
etc...
```

The number of lists is variable since the data file length can be variable.

Comment: the first line of the file is always ###.... ?

Comment: Yes and I need it to be the delimiter of each lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    master_list = []
    lst = []
    for i in data:
        if '#' in i:
            master_list.append(lst)
            lst = []
        else:
            lst.append(i.replace('\n', ''))
```

Drop the first element

````
master_list[1:]

['Data1', '133', '124', 'FRE', 'new', 'Cable', 'Sat'], ['DataB', '233', '445', 'DEU', 'Old', 'Sat'], ['MyValue', '4566', '455', 'ITA', 'NEW'], ['MyValue5', '455', '22332', 'Eng', 'Sat', 'Cable']]```
````

Comment: This is a good solution but at the end I don't ust master_list[1:] but :  list2 = [x for x in master_list if x]  

print(list2)

Answer (score 1):

This will convert the file to a list of lists instead of the named variables after reading the file into a string using an intermediate character, `/` here, but you could change that if it's in other places in your data.

```
data = [line.split('\n') for line in re.sub('\n?#+\n?', '/', text).split('/')]
```

If you prefer the names, you could do something similar for a dictionary, which will likely be better than individual variables.

```
data = {'mylist' + str(line[0]): line[1].split('\n') for line in enumerate(re.sub('\n?#+\n?', '/', text).split('/'))}
```

Both of these will have an extra list if there are separators at the top or bottom of the file like in the post, but you could chop those off if needed.

If you really need to assign to variables, you could use `exec` to set them, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Answer (score 0):

the version of python >3.5
I do not quite understand what you mean， What I need is to put each of them into a list *and the separator must be the #*？
the example of your result doesn't match your requirements. Maybe you want:

```
filepath = "./data.txt" # the full pathname of your data file
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f: # get data
    data = f.readlines()
# handle data
for item in data[1:]:
    if "#" in item:
        print(myList)
        myList = []
        continue
    myList.append(item.strip("\n"))
```

The result is shown below：

```
['Data1', '133', '124', 'FRE', 'new', 'Cable', 'Sat']
['DataB', '233', '445', 'DEU', 'Old', 'Sat']
['MyValue', '4566', '455', 'ITA', 'NEW']
['MyValue5', '455', '22332', 'Eng', 'Sat', 'Cable']
```

if the number of the separator (#) is all the same
it's easy to handle your problem by the faction of "split" like below:

```
filepath = "./data.txt" # the full pathname of your data file
with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f: # get data
    # f.readline()  # fiter the first line
    data = f.read()
data = data.strip("#").strip("\n").split("###########################\n")
for item in data:
    print(item.split("\n"))
```

I'm shame that I'm a newbie for the site so not have enough reputation to post an image.

Comment: you mention "result is shown below" but there is no result section. Could you please put it in?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't konw why the picture can't show. the result of my program is like:
['Data1', '133', '124', 'FRE', 'new', 'Cable', 'Sat']
['DataB', '233', '445', 'DEU', 'Old', 'Sat']
['MyValue', '4566', '455', 'ITA', 'NEW']
['MyValue5', '455', '22332', 'Eng', 'Sat', 'Cable']